# Django templating: is it possible to read field attributes of a form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Here's my form:

```
class ProfileForm(FormForceLocalizedDateFields):

    class Meta:
        model = Personne
        fields = ('sex', )
        exclude = ('user',)

    e = {'required': _(u'This field is required'),
         'invalid': _(u'This field contains invalid data')}

    a = _(u'Sexe:')
    sexe = forms.CharField(
        label=a, max_length=1,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            'title': a,
            'data-row': 1,
            'class': 'form-control'},
            choices=[(k, Personne.TAB_SEXE[k]) for k in Personne.TAB_SEXE]),
        error_messages=e)
```

If you read carefully you'll notice my custom attribute `'data-row': 1,`

Here's what I'd like to do in my template:

```
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.attr("data-row")==1 %}
            Blabla
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Ok thank you may I ask you to answer so I can check your answer as valid? I'm using the `{% if field.field.widget.attrs.datarow == 0 %}` to do something, it works but I dont know if it's the right way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the attribute name `datarow` then you can do something like

```
{% if field.field.widget.attrs.datarow == 0 %}
```

However, you can't use the attribute `data-row` because of the hyphen. If you really need to do this, you can use a custom template filter that supports dictionary lookups.